# Diminuindo o valor de dois campos de uma tabela e ordenando de acordo com o resultado

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, mysql

Tenho o campo "matou" e "morreu" na tabela, preciso fazer com que a ordem dos resultados venha conforme a diminuição desses dois valores, Exemplo:

Minha query está assim:

```
$woes = DB::table('woeplayerrank as woe')
        ->join('char', 'woe.char_id', '=', 'char.char_id')
        ->select('woe.kills_permanente', 'woe.deaths_permanente', 'woe.killen_spree', 'woe.name', 'char.unban_time', 'char.class')
        ->orderBy('woe.kills_permanente', 'ansi')
        ->take('100');
```

Gostaria que fosse algo em torno disso:

```
$woes = DB::table('woeplayerrank as woe')
        ->join('char', 'woe.char_id', '=', 'char.char_id')
        ->select('woe.kills_permanente', 'woe.deaths_permanente', 'woe.killen_spree', 'woe.name', 'char.unban_time', 'char.class')
        ->orderByRaw('woe.kills_permanente - woe.deaths_permanente ansi)
        ->take('100');
```

Alguém sabe me dizer como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize parênteses para realizar a subtração:

```
$woes = DB::table('woeplayerrank as woe')
        ->join('char', 'woe.char_id', '=', 'char.char_id')
        ->select('woe.kills_permanente', 'woe.deaths_permanente', 'woe.killen_spree', 'woe.name', 'char.unban_time', 'char.class')
        ->orderByRaw('(kills_permanente - deaths_permanente)')
        ->take('100');
```

Comment: Só pra deixar registrado, os campos não podem está marcado como unsigned na tabela.

Answer (score 1):

O que você quer em SQL ficaria assim:

```
SELECT woe.kills_permanente,
  woe.deaths_permanente,
  woe.killen_spree,
  woe.name,
  char.unban_time,
  char.class,
  woe.kills_permanente - woe.deaths_permanente AS orders
FROM woeplayerrank AS woe INNER JOIN char AS char ON woe.char_id = char.char_id
ORDER BY orders ANSI LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Desculpe minha inexperiência, mas depois de algumas tentativas não consegui fazer sua solução rodar ! teria algum meio alternativo?